# Insert into sql Max +1 only numbers (prevent characters)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm using this code

```
(SELECT (MAX(CODE)   +1  WHERE ISNUMERIC([code]) = 1)
```

I want to max +1 only my numbers of my column preventing characters characters.

Comment: You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE:  THIS QUESTION WAS TAGGED MYSQL WHEN THIS ANSWER WAS POSTED.

You can use `substring_index()` to split the values and then re-unite them:

```
(SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(Code), '-', 1), '-',
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(CODE), '-', -1) + 1
              ) 
 FROM . . .
 WHERE code LIKE '%NEW-1%'
)
```

This assumes that the wildcards do not have hyphens in them, and that the values after the "1" are all numbers.

Also, this doesn't pad the number is zeroes, but that is a good idea for such codes -- it ensures that they are always the same length and that they sort correctly.

Comment: i get error SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.Maybe cause i use sql 2000

Comment: Sorry. Or how can i prevent columns with characters? Just to max +1 to last column with numbers

Comment: You can prevent columns with characters using `INT` as column type rather than `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

The [MAX() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187751(v=sql.90).aspx) accepts expressions, not just column names:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE ISNUMERIC(code) WHEN 1 THEN code END)+1 as next_code
FROM (
    SELECT '15' AS code
    UNION ALL SELECT ' 98 ' AS code
    UNION ALL SELECT 'New-45' AS code
) foo
WHERE ISNUMERIC(code)=1;
```

```
16
```

*(Link is to SQL Server 2005, docs for SQL Server 2000 are apparently no longer on line, but `MAX()` belongs to SQL standard anyway.)*